# React app is rendering blank page intermittently

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application running in React, and I have multiple links on a page. When I click on these links, sometime it renders a blank page with no network error shown in the developer console. However, if I were to refresh the page, it will load the page correctly. Also, the page will load correctly if I open the links in new tabs.

Comment: Please share your code. Your question is impossible to answer without it.

Comment: This happens sometimes when running Create React App or Create Next App in development mode. Won't happen in the production build